# Tagged addresses

Tags: data-request, corpora, nlp, usa

Does anyone know of a corpus of US addresses where the parts of the addresses have been tagged.

Something like

```
<streetNumber>123</streetNumber> 
<streetDirection>E.</streetDirection>
<streetName>Main</streetName> 
<streetType>Rd.</streetType>
,
<place>Chicago</place>
<state>IL</state>
<postalCode>60647</postalCode>
```

I'm *not* looking for a corpus of addresses like OpenAddresses. I'm also not looking for a data standard for tagging addresses like the [United States Thoroughfare, Landmark, and Postal Address Data Standard](https://www.fgdc.gov/standards/projects/FGDC-standards-projects/street-address/index_html).

I'm looking for a corpus of addresses, where the parts of the addresses have been tagged. Something like [this](https://github.com/datamade/us-address-parser/blob/master/training/data/us50.test.tagged).

Answer (score 3):

http://openaddresses.io/

It's an initiative to collect open (CC0) addresses around Unites States and globally.
You could transform these as you like..

Answer (score 2):

microformats do that, off hand look @ web data commons for a large repo:
http://webdatacommons.org/
more real world examples from microformats wiki:
http://microformats.org/wiki/dataset-examples#Real-World_Examples

Answer (score 2):

If the number of addresses is thousands at a time, and not more, you can use the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for free. You can even use the API without a key for small sets of addresses.

The URL looks like this:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Museum für  Gestaltung Zurich Switzerland](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Museum%20f%C3%BCr%20Gestaltung%2CZurich%2CSwitzerland)

And returns a JSON with structured and normalized data (click link above to see JSON response)

---

Downside:

> The Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_12).

Comment: It's not open data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Texas A&M's [Address Parsing and Normalization](http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/AddressNormalization/) service to turn any set of addresses into a tagged set of addresses.